# Strategies to conserve filters

Tags: covid-19, face-mask-respirator

If using reusable elastomeric respirators with dual filters (e.g. 3M 6200, 7502, or 6800) in medical settings with potential contact with Covid positive people, in order to conserve the limited number of filters (e.g. 3M 2091, 2097, 7091, or 7093), is it advisable to just seal one inhalation valve completely shut, so as to use only 1 filter cartridge per person? Is there a concern with this method?